# Python send my e-email to gmail, but not send to outlook or work address

Tags: python

My python code send a e-mail from my work aaddress to my gmail address, but they not send to any outlook address or work address.
When I send the email it appears in the sent box, regardless of whether it was delivered or not.

```
import smtplib
import mimetypes
import email
import email.mime.application
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

_from = 'myaddress@work.com.br'
_pass = 'pass'  
_to = ['mygmail@gmail.com','myaddress@work.com.br']

msg = email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Test'
msg['From'] = 'myaddress@work.com.br'
msg['To'] = ", ".join(_to)

body = MIMEText('Hi, this is a test email.<br><img src="cid:image"> <br>Thanks!.', 'html')
msg.attach(body)

fp = open('C:/Users/renan.p.costa/img.png', 'rb')
image = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
image.add_header('Content-ID', '<image>')
msg.attach(image)

file='C:/Users/renan.p.costa/file.xlsx'
_filename='file.xlsx'
fp=open(file,'rb')
excelfile = email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(fp.read(),_subtype="xlsx")
fp.close()
anexo.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=_filename)
msg.attach(excelfile)

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.login(_from,_pass)
s.sendmail(msg['From'],msg['To'], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to send a list of emails (`_to`) instead of a string of emails separated by , so you need a list of to-address strings (a bare string will be treated as a list with 1 address). 
In your code, you can modify the line:

```
s.sendmail(msg['From'],msg['To'], msg.as_string())
```

by this other one:

```
s.sendmail(msg['From'],_to, msg.as_string())
```

**EDIT**

If it doesn't work, you can try iterating the list, so you make diferent sendmails for every email in the list:

```
for to_email in _to:
    s.sendmail(msg['From'],to_email, msg.as_string())
```